# How do I add styling using a chrome extension?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I made an extension for myself in order to change the styling for gmail, but it doesn't seem to be working. The manifest is below - an icon for the extension appears in the standard bar, and it does indicate (when hovering) that permission is granted on gmail and not for other sites.

```
{
  "name": "XXXXXX",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "description": "Do It!",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://mail.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["styles.css"]
    }
  ]
}
```

The styles.css file is in the same directory as the manifest. If I open the inspector-stylesheet within chrome developer tools and paste in the contents of the stylesheet, the desired effects occur. So it seem the issue is that for some reason the style.css file isn't being recognized/loaded. Any idea what the issue could be? Am I missing something?

Comment: Your rules may have been overridden. Use `!important` or raise the specificity artificially.

Comment: Use `document_end` in the content script rule. It will prevent CSS overriding.
From the docs: `document_end: Scripts are injected immediately after the DOM is complete, but before subresources like images and frames have loaded.`